# Upload photo in background with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm a bit new to ajax, I just want to see if anyone can help me with this...
I have my main page. I'll just put the element I'm working with so I don't have to put the whole page.

```
<input type="file" id="myphoto" />
```

Then, instead of submitting it, what I want to do is run it through a javascript function with an ajax form in it like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myphppage.php",
    "Whatever other code needed"
})
```

to upload the photo. Then, the form URL could be a php page that moves the photo to a different directory. I hope you know what I mean. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: Just explore about how to do file upload. AJAX calls are always in background and you can optionally include a callback function.

Answer (score 3):

first make a html file which select the file from anywhere, like

**uplaod.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AJAX UPLOAD</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="upload.js"></script>
</html>
```

now, make js file like below,

**upload.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);

$.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', 
            dataType: 'text',  
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                         
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data); 
            }
 });
});
});
```

now, make a directory **uploads** and a php file which upload the file to **upload** directory

**upload.php**

```
<?php

if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    echo "success";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XHR2 AJAX request can submit binary data like images:

[DEMO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

However, changing the address bar (windows.location) will interrupt the upload as the new page is loaded. You can work around of this by loading pages via AJAX and using History API:

[Demo1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file)

Comment: this'll be pretty neat in a few years